# quotation marks on attributes SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Is there a difference between the following two queries?

```
CREATE TABLE alpha(age INTEGER);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE alpha("age" INTEGER);
```

I read that database objects are case **INSENSITIVE** unless they are kept in quotation marks.
This applies when I try to keep the TABLE object in quotation marks but isn't working for the attributes.

I guess the reason is attributes are not database objects. Is this correct?

If yes, then in what category does attributes fall under, if not database object?

Comment: In your example there, "age" is a column, not an attribute.

Comment: But the syntax for CREATE reserve word is:

CREATE objecttype objectName attributes;

So I think it must be an attribute as per the syntax.

Comment: CREATE creates many thing.  When we're talking about tables, age is a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a difference ? yes.

when you don't use quotes, like:

```
CREATE TABLE alpha(age INTEGER);
```

oracle will store that column and table as UPPERCASE in the data dictionary.

in other words , these statements are identical:

```
CREATE TABLE alpha(age INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE "ALPHA"("AGE" INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE ALPHA(AGE INTEGER);
```

Also, any subsequent dml/ddl on the table like:

```
select age from alpha;
```

would be first converted to uppercase when looking up the object/column; so the above SQL would work fine. i.e oracle would look for the column `AGE` and the table `ALPHA` and not the column `age` or the table `alpha` as was typed.

however, when you create with a quoted identifier:

```
CREATE TABLE alpha("age" INTEGER);
```

oracle would create table `ALPHA` with a column in lowercase `age` (check `user_tab_columns` to see this). so ONLY the following would work to select it:

```
select "age" from alpha;
select "age" from "ALPHA";
select "age" from ALPHA;
```

and not:

```
select age from alpha;
```

eg:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3084e/1

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the database engine, and even how the database itself or the connected session is configured. However, in general, [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) would treat `age` and `"age"` as the same identifier, while [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/sql_elements008.htm) would consider `age` and `"age"` to be different.

In regard to attributes (columns), treatment of those identifiers vary widely as well. Most database engines will allow the attributes to be identified by quotation marks (or other delimiters) and in the same way the table identifiers are handled.

Comment: Thank you fr such promt responses! :)

I am using Oracle 11g here.

One more interesting point I just found is that when i execute the following query:

CREATE TABLE gamma ("aGe" INTEGER);

then in this case the attribute is stored as aGe only.

That means ONLY:

SELECT "aGe" from gamma;

works!

While for table alpha,

SELECT "AGE" from alpha;
SELECT AGE from alpha;
SELECT age from alpha;

all worked!

I can't find the commonality here in treating the attributes in quotes.

Comment: When quotes are used to define in Oracle, then the attribute can only be referenced in quotes with exactly the same casing used, otherwise it is case-insensitive and displays in upper-case. The Oracle link in the answer alludes to this when it says "If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you must use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object.".